# Let $T,S: C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$, such that $S(x)(z)=z\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt$, $T(x)(z)=s\cdot x(s)$. Calculate $||S||, ||T||, ||ST||$ e $||TS||$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I know that $||T||=||S||=||TS||=1$, because I was able to calculate this. But, for $||ST||$, we had $||ST||\leq ||S|| ||T||=1$ and  $$||(S\circ T)(x)||_{\infty}=\sup_{z\in [0,1]}|z|\left|\int_{0}^1tx(t)dt\right|=\left|\int_{0}^1tx(t)dt\right|.$$

How $ST\neq TS$ trying to find a function $x_0\in C[0,1]$ such that $||ST(x_0)||_{\infty} \geq 1$. However, I'm starting to give up on that idea.

Comment: I'm a little confused of what you have already calculated and what you still haven't. Fo the case $T\circ S$, $x_0(s)\equiv 1$, doesn't prove that $||TS(x_0)||_{\infty} \geq 1$?

Comment: @alphaomega Sorry! I have corrected the errors in the question, I hope it is clear enough. I couldn't calculate $||ST||$, i am imagined it is 1.

Comment: actually $x_0(t) \equiv 1$ and your calculations give again that $||ST(x_0)||_{\infty} \geq 1$.

Comment: @alphaomega If $x_0(t)\equiv 1$, we had $||ST(x_0)||\geq \frac{1}{2}$ (if we use the what $||ST(x_0)||=|\int_0^1tdt|=|1/2-0|=1/2$). Or could there be another strategy?

Comment: you are right. use then $x_0\equiv 2$

Comment: @alphaomega we need that $||x_0||_{\infty}=1$, for use the definition of norm of operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$. Then
$$\|(S\circ T)(x)\|_{\infty}=\left|\int_{0}^1tx(t)dt\right| \leq \int_{0}^1\left|tx(t)\right|dt = \int_{0}^1 t \left|x(t)\right|dt \leq \|x\|_{\infty}\cdot \int_0^1 t dt = \int_0^1 t dt = \frac{1}{2} $$

Thus $\| S\circ T \|_{op} \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

On the other hand, if $x_0\equiv 1$, then $\|x_0\|_{\infty}=1$ and $\|(S\circ T)(x_0)\|_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$

Hence, $\| S\circ T \|_{op}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks my friend! I am trying to prove something that is not true.

Comment: @RodolfoCardoso yes me too in the comments! but your replies hleped me